# Manipulating Custom User Controls Given Only (x,y) Screen Coordinates (without Mouse)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls, expression-blend

Given only an (x,y) point on the screen (without being allowed to use the mouse), how can you manipulate a custom UserControl?

For example, I have a custom slider that I want to manipulate using only an x, y returned by a vision code (the vision code acts like a mouse, but I am not actually supposed to use the mouse).

Comment: Not "supposed" to use the mouse... is this an assignment of some sort?

Comment: What you mean? UIAutomation? Couldn't get you. Please provide more info

Answer (score 0):

How does the mouse normally interact with the custom **UserControl**? Does the **UserControl** have an **EventHandler** when the mouse clicks/moves on it? If so, you can call the Control's **Mouse_Click** event (for example) from elsewhere in the code and pass in the arguments that you want. You can do this with code logic or other controls with the same parent as your UserControl.

Ideally, you can set your UserControl up so that it doesn't interact with the mouse directly. Rather, the Control and Mouse both get/set a shared variable representing the XY of the mouse. This makes things easier to test. What you want to use is Binding.